# Detecting input changes

Tags: javascript

I am having a simple text input field and from a different function am setting it's value.

What way can I detect such change?

Tried multiple solutions, listening of particular events such as:
***paste, input, keyup, keydown, change*** but none of them is triggered. Tried as well ***MutationObserver*** but this does not work on inputs fields only DOM tree changes.

Any clues?

Comment: Do you have some code we could look at?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by adding a custom property with a custom setter. Like this:

```js
// Get the input
var input = document.getElementById("input")

// Create the class
class inputElement {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element
    
    // For when the user changes the input
    this.element.addEventListener("input", this.edited)
    
    // For when JS changes the input
    Object.defineProperty(this, "value", {
      get() {
        return this.element.value
      },
      set(val) {
        this.element.value = val
        this.edited()
      }
    })
  }

  // Runs on edit
  edited() {
    alert("This was edited!")
  }
}

// Create a new object for the element
input = new inputElement(input)

// Example of changing the input's text
function addText() {
  input.value += "Hello world!"
}
```

```html
Text:<br>
<input type="text" id="input">
<br><br>
<button onclick="addText()">Add Text</button>
```

This creates a custom class with `getter` and `setterr` so when it is changed with JavaScript or by the user, it runs the function. Just create a new class with the element and change the edited function!

When the `addFunction` button is pressed, it runs js that sets the value.

**Note:** If you want to change any of the input's properties *other than input*, you must use `input.element`.
For example:

```
//Change value:
input.value = "123"

//Change style (color):
input.element.style.color = "red
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an input element like below:

```
<input type="text" id="myInputElement"/>
```

Then you could queryselect the id attribute of the element to find it in the DOM using JavaScript and store it inside a variable

```
var inputElement = document.querySelector("#myInputElement");
```

After which you can detect changes by applying an event listener to it, like so:

```
inputElement.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    // your code
});
```

Inside the callback function you can do anything you like, this function will only be called when the input changes, you could for instance console log the current value using the event parameter that is automatically passed to the callback function:

```
 inputElement.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
});
```

That's basically the gist of it :)

Comment: this will be triggered on manual input field changes, I wanna detect it when value is set only from the js level

Comment: I see, well then i would define a higher level (or even global depending on your code) boolean variable and , set this to true upon a change. In the other function i would check for this variable, if it's true, you know for a fact something in the input field has changed.